# Modifying a server to allow multiple clients to connect concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable, concurrent-programming

So I've created a server and a client for a previous part of the assignment, but now I have to extend/modify the server so that it can handle multiple clients concurrently.
I know I have to do something along the lines of

```
Server server1 = new Server();

Thread thread = new Thread(server1);

thread.start();
```

and have the Class Server implement Runnable.

But the lecturers notes on multi-threading are not very clear and I have been starring at this part of the question for a long time and have got no where.

Below is the code I have written for one client at a time to connect to the server.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Server.java

```
public class Server {

    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

    private Socket s;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Server serverInstance = new Server();
        System.out.println("Server running. Waiting for a client to connect...");
        while (true) {
            serverInstance.s = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            serverInstance.run();
            System.out.println("Client disconnected. Waiting for a new client to connect...");
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                doService(); // the actual service
            }
            finally {
                s.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void doService() throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            if (!in.hasNext())
                return;
            String request = in.next();
            System.out.println("Request received: " + request);
            // (...) test for type of request here (not implemented)
            Request(request);
        }
    }

    public void Request(String request) {

        String amountStr = in.next();
        if (request.startsWith("SUBMIT")) {
            if (tokens.size() < 10) {
                tokens.add(amountStr);
                System.out.println("Token added");
                out.println("OK");
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Error");
                out.println("Error");
            }
        }
        else if (request.startsWith("REMOVE")) {
            if (tokens.contains(amountStr)) {
                tokens.remove(amountStr);
                System.out.println("Tokens removed");
                out.println("OK");
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Error");
                out.println("Error");
            }

        }
        else if (request.equals("QUIT")) {
            System.err.println("Program ended");
            out.println("Program ended");
        }

        tokens.sort(null);
        System.out.println(tokens);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
         InputStream instream = s.getInputStream();
         OutputStream outstream = s.getOutputStream();
         Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
         String request = "SUBMIT hello \n";
         out.print(request);
         out.flush();
         String response = in.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Token: " + response);
         s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read a tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ for example), and try something. Your lecturer's notes are not the only place where freely available information about multithreading is available. The whole web is at your disposal.

Comment: Have you tried `executorservice` , `semaphore`??

Comment: Generally, you want a single thread to listen for new connections that spawns new threads or tasks as connections arrive.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to duplicate is what RMI has been doing for decades. Java is open source so you can look at how RMI works and learn from there. You can also look on the internet for myriad examples of multi threaded servers with/without RMI.